# Scrapy returns the text of an element in shell but not in the code

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, webdriver, scrapy-shell

I'm new to web scraping and have been learning Scrapy and Selenium for the last couple of days. I'm trying to extract some info from this source: https://www.kodda.co.kr/kr/information/member.php
To be specific, I need a company name, CEO name, and email. So far I was able to write code that clicks buttons to navigate to various pages. Currently, I want to extract the info from the table of a given page.

For example, given this table:
[The screenshot of a table code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl4r1.png)
I'd like to extract the text inside the first  tag. When I write this code on scrapy shell: `response.xpath('//table[@class="sub-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/text()').get()` it returns what's inside the first  (which is what I want). But when I write this exact code on a .py file and run it, it returns empty (""):

```
import scrapy

class CompanyInfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'company_info'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.kodda.co.kr/kr/information/member.php']
    start_urls = ['http://https://www.kodda.co.kr/kr/information/member.php/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.xpath('//table[@class="sub-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/text()').get())
```

I tried the same thing using Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=show_browser(False))
driver.get("https://www.kodda.co.kr/kr/information/member.php")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

column_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@class="sub-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')
column_text = column_element.text
time.sleep(10)

print(column_text)
```

But this also returns empty (""). I've been googling for hours but couldn't find any possible reason.

Note: I've also tried explicit wait:

```
ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException,)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)
wait.until(lambda wd: column_text != "")
```

Attempted: `wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "sub-table")))` but these also returned empty ("")

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue! I tracked it down to `text` function. For some reason that I didn't care to search for, `text` doesn't work when I use it to extract the text of an element. Instead, `get_attribute("innerText")` worked!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong locator.
This locator matches 10 elements on the page, but these elements are not visible, at least not the first one. Since you are using `driver.find_element` method it returns you the first match of the passed locator on the page.
Also you should use Expected Conditions explicit waits, not a `implicitly_wait` since the former method waits for element existence only, it will not wait for the element complete rendered. So using this method you are getting the `column_element` element on the stage when it is still not fully rendered, still not populated with the text content it will finally have.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I'm aware that there are other elements with the same class name and that I'm getting the first match. Then, I don't understand why would the shell return the expected outcome. Do you think the shell is somehow going past the invisible table/s?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. This also may be caused by the use of `implicitly_wait`

Comment: In order to check if the problem caused by implicitly wait just put the `time.sleep(10)` before `column_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@class="sub-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')`. Please let me know it that worked.

Comment: Yea it would make sense if the element contents are not fully rendered during scraping. Here is what I tried instead of ```implicitly_wait```:                               
   ```expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "sub-table"))```   i.e. wait for 50 seconds until all tables with class name "sub-table" become visible, but this gave a time out error

Comment: Also tried putting ```time.sleep(10)``` before ```column_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@class="sub-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')``` but that also returned empty ("")